# tools to automate the script webdriver in jmeter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, katalon-studio, software-quality

is there any tools which can make the automation script for webdriver in Jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just copy and paste the existing code as JMeter's WebDriver Sampler plugin:

1. Doesn't allow you to use [DesiredCapabilities](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/configuration.html#desiredCapabilities)
2. You need to rename your [WebDriver](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) instances to `WDS.browser`
3. I don't think JUnit annotations will be processed properly.

The easiest way to run existing Selenium tests written in Java using JUnit framework is [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler. All you need is to package your tests as .jar file and drop them under "lib/junit" folder of your JMeter installation.

After JMeter restart you will be able to see your test class and method(s) names(s) in the JUnit Request sampler and hence it will be possible to run your test with increased number of threads.

More information: [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter)

Comment: The detailed answer was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to perform load testing, then I would prefer Jmeter. and to automate application in web browser, selenium web driver is perfect way. but as u want to automate script webdriver using Jmeter u need to integrate it using plugins of Jmeter.

U can directly pass URL in Jmeter and directly redirect to URL as well.